# Multiplication issue with Visual Studio debugger for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, overflow, unchecked

If I enter 174 * 256 * 256 * 256 into the watch window in the C# debugger, the result is
-1375731712.  I assume it has something to do with 256, but I'd appreciate a little guidance.

Thanks!!

Comment: It's because of integer overflow.

Comment: I would assume this would have something to do with an integer overflow. Don't quote me on this, but it is possible that the watch window's default integer type is 32 bit. Because of this limit, the multiplication goes over the maximum value and ends up overflowing into the negatives.

Comment: @invalidsyntax: It's not the default of the window, but of the language.  An undecorated integer literal is interpreted as an Int32 in C#.

Comment: @Eric Mickelsen -- thanks for the clarification.

Comment: So what you guys are saying is that this is an integer overflow?  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enter this:

```
174 * 256 * 256 * 256f
```

so result will not get cast to integer but as float.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, nothing to do with 256.  It's just the result of that multiplication is larger than the maximum possible signed 32-bit integer, so you got an overflow.

Try this instead:

```
174L * 256L * 256L * 256L
```

Those are 64-bit integer literals.

Comment: Interesting.  Why no exception thrown?

Comment: @Mike C.: Integer multiplication is a processor-level instruction, which is extremely fast.  Checking for overflow would be inordinately expensive for such a low-level operation.  Math with arbitrary size or arbitrary precision requires datatypes that don't have a fixed size, which are often called "Big".

Comment: @Mike C: If you want integer arithmetic to throw an exception on overflow in your C# program then (1) "x = checked(a*b);", (2) "checked { x = a*b; }, or (3) there is a "make checked the default" switch on the compiler. Similarly there is "unchecked" to force the opposite behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It does an `unchecked` overflow (so an overflow withouth error). Think like this: Int32.MaxValue + 1 == Int32.MinValue, but with multiplication.

This explains how an int is represented in memory
  [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement](http://Two%27s%20complement)

Answer (score 0):

You are facing an integer overflow. You can use the `System.Numerics.BigInteger` if you want to work with big numbers without limitation (beside the available memory of course). In your special case a `long` would also do (64 bit integer)

Answer (score 0):

You are overflowing the integer.  The real answer is 2,919,235,584 but only up to 2,147,483,647 can be represented as a signed integer.  Consider an unsigned int (uint), a long, a ulong, or if that isn't big enough.  For the watch window you'd probably have to cast the first argument or use a suffix, e.g. 174L * 256L * 256L * 256L

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple overflow. Try to enter this in your watch window:

```
(uint)(174 * 256 * 256 * 256)
```